# Crontab to run a bash script that runs multiple python scripts

Tags: python, linux, bash, cron

I'm a beginner in linux. I want run multiple python scripts every 30 second and I'm planning to do this using a bash script ( to run multiple python scripts simultaneously) and crontab (to schedule the scripts to run every 30 sec).

This is how my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script is used to run multiple python script to query all types and all modes of GTFSR data

#Set working directory
cd "${0%/*}"

#BUS Query Real Time
python gtfsrdb_tfnsw.py -p 'https://api.transport.nsw.gov.au/v1/gtfs/vehiclepos/buses' --database="postgresql://localhost/test" —apikey="XXX" -m "buses" -c -1 &
python gtfsrdb_tfnsw.py -t 'https://api.transport.nsw.gov.au/v1/gtfs/realtime/buses' --database="postgresql://localhost/test" --apikey="XXX" -m "buses" -c -1 &
python gtfsrdb_tfnsw.py -a 'https://api.transport.nsw.gov.au/v1/gtfs/alerts/buses' --database="postgresql://localhost/test" --apikey="XXX" -m "buses" -c -1 &

#Sydney Train Real Time
python gtfsrdb_tfnsw.py -p 'https://api.transport.nsw.gov.au/v1/gtfs/vehiclepos/sydneytrains' --database="postgresql://localhost/test" --apikey="XXX" -m "sydneytrains" -c -1 &
python gtfsrdb_tfnsw.py -t 'https://api.transport.nsw.gov.au/v1/gtfs/realtime/sydneytrains' --database="postgresql://localhost/test" --apikey="XXX" -m "sydneytrains" -c -1 &
python gtfsrdb_tfnsw.py -a 'https://api.transport.nsw.gov.au/v1/gtfs/alerts/sydneytrains' --database="postgresql://localhost/test" --apikey="XXX" -m "sydneytrains" -c -1 &

#Ferries Real Time
python gtfsrdb_tfnsw.py -p 'https://api.transport.nsw.gov.au/v1/gtfs/vehiclepos/ferries' --database="postgresql://localhost/test" --apikey="XXX" -m "ferries" -c -1 &
python gtfsrdb_tfnsw.py -t 'https://api.transport.nsw.gov.au/v1/gtfs/realtime/ferries' --database="postgresql://localhost/test" --apikey="XXX" -m "ferries" -c -1 &
python gtfsrdb_tfnsw.py -a 'https://api.transport.nsw.gov.au/v1/gtfs/alerts/ferries' --database="postgresql://localhost/test" --apikey="XXX" -m "ferries" -c -1 &

#lightrail Real Time
python gtfsrdb_tfnsw.py -p 'https://api.transport.nsw.gov.au/v1/gtfs/vehiclepos/lightrail' --database="postgresql://localhost/test" --apikey="XXX" -m "lightrail" -c -1 &
python gtfsrdb_tfnsw.py -t 'https://api.transport.nsw.gov.au/v1/gtfs/realtime/lightrail' --database="postgresql://localhost/test" --apikey="XXX" -m "lightrail" -c -1 &
python gtfsrdb_tfnsw.py -a 'https://api.transport.nsw.gov.au/v1/gtfs/alerts/lightrail' --database="postgresql://localhost/test" --apikey="XXX" -m "lightrail" -c -1 &

#nswtrains Real Time
python gtfsrdb_tfnsw.py -p 'https://api.transport.nsw.gov.au/v1/gtfs/vehiclepos/nswtrains' --database="postgresql://localhost/test" --apikey="XXX" -m "nswtrains" -c -1 &
python gtfsrdb_tfnsw.py -t 'https://api.transport.nsw.gov.au/v1/gtfs/realtime/nswtrains' --database="postgresql://localhost/test" --apikey="XXX" -m "nswtrains" -c -1 &
python gtfsrdb_tfnsw.py -a 'https://api.transport.nsw.gov.au/v1/gtfs/alerts/nswtrains' --database="postgresql://localhost/test" --apikey="XXX" -m "nswtrains" -c -1 &
```

This is what I put in crontab:

```
# GTFSR to Database
* * * * * ( /bin/bash /home/amarinS/projects/TfNSW_GTFSRDB/GTFSR_call)
* * * * * ( sleep 30 ; /bin/bash /home/amarinS/projects/TfNSW_GTFSRDB/GTFSR_call)
```

If I run `/bin/bash /home/amarinS/projects/TfNSW_GTFSRDB/GTFSR_call` manually, the bash script works fine. However nothing happens when the job is run via CRONTAB.

Please help.

Cheers!

Comment: Try put an infinite loop inside the bash script and add the `sleep 30` at the end. Add this to crontab `@reboot bin/bash /path/to/script/GTFSR_call`. And reboot the machine to make sure. Than your scrpit will run in background as you reboot the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are creating the cron entries as root. I have had that get me in the past.

Verify your env variables and the python interpreter.

Make sure all the scripts are executable.

Answer (score 0):

1. it might be that the script, running from crontab, is lacking some environment variables that it needs in order to run properly.
   see if [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables) helps
2. it might be beneficial to redirect the bash output (both stdout and stderr) to a log file so that you can know why it failed
3. (a side note): putting sleep 30 in your cron definition sounds like a bad idea. why did you do that?

Comment: I use sleep 30 because the default crontab will run every 1 minute. So I worked around by setting the second job to run after 30 seconds. This results the same script running every 30 sec. Is there a better way to do this ?